# Trying to find information on security for Files attached to Activities. Can you separate it out?

Tags: security, activities

I'm struggling somewhat to find anything on the File Attachment related list in Activities. What I am hoping is to be able to limit who can see/download the file and remove it from being searchable. What I have found so far is that it is not possible, but I am hoping I just haven't found the right answer yet.

Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is very little control on some of the special objects, that includes tasks, activities and attachments. They follow its related record's security. In this case, file attachment follows its parent record.

You can try to experiment with OWD for Activities as described [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000giCuAAI).